# Maven dependency to use com.google.common.graph.ImmutableDirectedGraph

Tags: java, maven, guava

I'd like to use the Guava collection com.google.common.graph.ImmutableDirectedGraph, [documented here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/ImmutableDirectedGraph.html), with Maven. I can't find the Maven dependency name and version including this particular class/API on the usual repositories.

What would be the correct Maven dependency/ies ?

Comment: Go to mvnrepository.com, and search for "guava".

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I think its reasonable to assume he did that, and in fact, the API in question hasn't been published there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like this API has been published to Maven central yet, but [I see it](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/graph/ImmutableDirectedGraph.java) in the latest snapshot, [20.0-SNAPSHOT on Github](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>20.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note that we're still in the process of making minor tweaks to the `com.google.common.graph` APIs. They should be relatively stable by the time Guava 20.0 is released.

Comment: Also note that the `ImmutableDirectedGraph` type is likely going to go away as part of those changes (you'll just use `ImmutableGraph` instead) and that by depending on `20.0-SNAPSHOT`, when that change happens and you get the new snapshot, your compile will fail.